# CSS draw circle inside circle, as display table-cell

Tags: css

I am trying to draw a solid circle inside a ring. I got the outer circle working great, but the inner one is filling up the entire circle whereas I want a few pixels inner padding.

I thought this would be simple but because I am using display:table for the container and table-cell for the inner bits padding/margin aren't behaving as I'd hope.

Example jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/5ewemw0q/ in this I'd like to have the red inner bit not take up the entire circle but have a few pixels spacing between it and the outer border.

The reason it's all table/table-cell is to easily manage vertically aligning the circle with its associated label.

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>label</label>
</div>

.radio {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
 }

.radio:before {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
}

.radio > label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How can I get the inner circle to have some inner padding? Tried margin,  padding, border-spacing, etc... all to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by making the parent relative and absolutely positioning the children, with the inner bits done by an :after pseudo element. Working great now

https://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/5ewemw0q/2/

```
.radio {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  position: relative;
 }

.radio:before {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.radio:after {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 16.5px;
  top: 16.5px;
}

.radio > label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  left: 42px;
  top: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a third color if you add a inset to box-shadow css.

`box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 1px yellow;`

https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/j3e78n4p/